# How to make a button destroy itself?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

How do I make the destroy button destroy itself with the destroy() function, and still be able to make a new destroy button with the create button?

```
from tkinter import Button, Tk

def create():
    b2 = Button(root, text='Destroy', command=destroy)
    b2.pack()

def destroy():
    b2.destroy()

root = Tk()

b1 = Button(root, text='Create', command=create)
b1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This works, you're just not taking the local scope of the function into consideration. Add `global b2` to your `create()` function or define it somewhere where scope won't be a factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from tkinter import *

def create():
    b = Button(root, text='Destroy')
    b.config(command=destroy(b))
    b.pack()

def destroy(button):
    def inner():
        button.destroy()
    return inner

root = Tk()

b1 = Button(root, text='Create', command=create)
b1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

We create a different callback for each new button, so we don't have to worry about scopes, and we can have more than destroy-able button.

Comment: You could also change this line to `b.config(command=lambda: destroy(b))` and remove the need for a wrapper function. The lambda is still essentially a wrapper but to me it's more apparent what is happening.

Comment: There's no need for an extra function. You can do `b.config(command=b.destroy)`.

Comment: @BryanOakley That's true... I didn't think of that :)